# How to convert a "plot" plotter into a "line.new" plotter?

Tags: pine-script

This code written by TradingView draws a plot with "plot" and I would like to do the same with "line.new" which will allow me to be able to dot the lines

Can you help me ?

```
oscHL = osc[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])
priceLL = low[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)
bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound

plot(plFound ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title="Regular Bullish", linewidth=2, color=(bullCond ? bullColor : noneColor))
```

Comment: You can style a `plot` also using the `style` parameter. You can try: `plot(plFound ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title="Regular Bullish", linewidth=2, color=(bullCond ? bullColor : noneColor), style=plot.style_circles)`

Comment: Thanks for answering.. I had already tried this but it only shows a circle.. I want to draw a dotted line and I believe it can only be done with "line.new"

Answer (score 0):

Using `line.new()` for this is overkill in my opinion. You won't have the complete plot this way too because there is a limit to number of lines you can have. Also, with `line.new()` you won't be able to see the values when you hover your mouse over the line.

If you really want to do it with `line.new()`, below is a simple example for you. It plots the same line (with some offset so you can see all three lines) using three different methods:

- `line.new()`
- plot with circles
- plot with line

Code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500)

offset = 100
ema10 = ta.ema(close, 10)

plot(ema10, color=color.green)
plot(ema10 + (offset * 1), color=color.yellow, style=plot.style_circles)
line.new(bar_index-1, ema10[1] + (offset * 2), bar_index, ema10 + (offset * 2), style=line.style_dashed, color=color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help I tried doing this but it doesn't work.. What am I doing wrong?

if plFound 
    line.new(bar_index-1, rsi[lbR], bar_index, rsi, style=line.style_dashed, color=bullCond ? color.green : na)
I would like to keep the "plot" with the "circle style" but it only displays a circle instead of several circles which represents the line